# Обрезать строки через Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обрезать строку вида

```
{"Name","ПетровА"},
{"Run mode","E"},
{"IsMono","N"},
{"Date&Time","00.00.2021,00:00:00"},
{"ComputerName","PC,pid=0000,spid=0,ip=192.168.0.0"}
```

чтоб на выходе, получать лишь содержимое вторых кавычек. Пробелов в них не бывает, но вот бывают точки, запятые.
Что то вроде такого

```
ПетровА
E
N
25.10.2021,07:10:53
```

А последнюю строку еще больше разбить надо.
Отдельно название PC, pid, spid, ip.

Я регулярные совершенно не понимаю(
Если в наглую нельзя, то был бы рад ссылкам на материалы для изучения.

Comment: откуда эта строка, и почему она выглядит как кусок C# кода? Вероятно есть более вменяемое решение распарсить это, чем регулярка.

Comment: @aepot Так себе JSON. Не массив, не объект, так, что-то посередёнке...

Comment: @aepot Ох, это логовый текстовик 1с.  Вам, он наверное знаком links.tmp с папки syslog. Там полный бардак. Кавычек там конечно нет. Весь файл такой

Comment: Вон оно что. Ну сейчас попробуем.

Comment: Нафиг тут регулярка? достаточно вульгарного String.Split по двойной кавычке с получением 4-го элемента массива. А для последнего значения - дополнительно сплит по запятой.

Comment: @Akina чем это проще простой регулярки `{"(.*?)","(.*?)"}`?

Comment: C# вроде позволяте квантификаторы в позитивном просмотре назад, можно попробовать вот так: `(?<=\{"[^"]+"\h*,\h*")[^"]+(?=")`  https://regex101.com/r/1WZaDa/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Паттерн получился такой `{"(.*?)","(.*?)"}`. Советую сайт https://regex101.com/ для тестирования регулярок - один из лучших, на мой взгляд.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = @"{""Name"",""ПетровА""},
{""Run mode"",""E""},
{""IsMono"",""N""},
{""Date&Time"",""00.00.2021,00:00:00""},
{""ComputerName"",""PC,pid=0000,spid=0,ip=192.168.0.0""}";
    var entries = ParseEntries(text);
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}: {entry.Value}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 15));

    string computerName = entries["ComputerName"];
    Dictionary<string, string> computer = computerName.Split(',')
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(pair => pair.Split('=').ToArray())
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);

    foreach (var pair in computer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static Dictionary<string, string> ParseEntries(string text)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"{""(.*?)"",""(.*?)""}"))
    {
        entries[match.Groups[1].Value] = match.Groups[2].Value;
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Name: ПетровА
Run mode: E
IsMono: N
Date&Time: 00.00.2021,00:00:00
ComputerName: PC,pid=0000,spid=0,ip=192.168.0.0
---------------
pid: 0000
spid: 0
ip: 192.168.0.0
```

Если структура данных константная, то можно и в класс распарсить с соответствующими свойствами. Но я остановился на словаре как на более общем решении.

Comment: Пока вы не дали ссылку, я не понимал, что за группы. А теперь, получил открытие века, для себя.  Это действительно работает. Постараюсь осилить эти регулярки. Спасибо Вам, в очередной раз

Comment: Нет. Все же я не понял до конца. Как например дальше получить содержимое последней строки, у 1го элемента массива, который мы обрезали? Т.е pid=0000. А нам нужно, его содержимое "0000". Делать Split строки?

Comment: @Espoit обновил ответ